# How to Migrate Google Apps account to regular Google Account

Tags: google-workspace, google-analytics, google-account

I currently have a free Google Apps for your Domain account, with only one email address in there. I will soon be moving from Google Mail to another hosted email solution (such as a hosted Exchange server).

As a result of this, I want to remove the "Google Apps" part from my domain, but retain all of the other services I use, such as Analytics and Webmaster Tools. This would need to move to a Google Account, with the same name as my current Google Apps account.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: 1. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91468/closing-google-apps-account-can-i-migrate-youtube-account-and-android-apps?rq=1, 2. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-do-i-migrate-a-gmail-account-to-a-google-apps-account/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to do this. It would seem such a feature has not been built by Google.

I ended up moving my mail account, linking my Analytics profiles to a separate GMail address, and then destroying my Google Apps domain. Not a great solution, but thankfully it worked as it turns out I didn't use too many other Google services.