# Closing Google Apps account: Can I migrate YouTube account and Android Apps?

Tags: youtube, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, google-play-store

I have a Google Apps account, which I use for my personal email and as my primary personal Google account. The Google Apps account is associated with my personal domain name.

I am thinking about closing my Google Apps account because I am interested in moving to a different email provider.

However, I have purchased Android apps through my Google Apps account. Is there any way for me to retain access to these apps after closing my Google Apps account? For example, can I migrate the purchases to a free Google account?

I also have a YouTube account associated with my Google Apps account. If I close my Google Apps account, will my videos stay up? If they do stay up, is there any way I can retain ownership of these videos? For example, can I transfer ownership of the videos to a different YouTube account? Can I migrate my YouTube account to be associated with a free Google account?

There are other things associated with my Google Apps account (e.g. Google Drive), but I don’t care about those so much. However I would welcome any insights into how to maintain access to other Google services, because other people reading this question might find them helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Google Play purchases can't be transferred from one account to another account.
- Youtube information can't be merged (transferred) from one account to another but Youtube channel ownership can be transferred if they are linked to a Google+ page.

Unfortunately there isn't a workaround for Google Play purchases, but Youtube videos could be downloaded.

## References

- [Transfer Purchases - Thread from the Google Play Help Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/QqPDdgw3yYY)
- [Merge YouTube channels (transfer data) - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2404846?hl=en)
- [Transfer ownership of a channel - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4627568?hl=en)
- [Download your own Youtube videos - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/56100?hl=en)

Comment: Are Google Play purchases gone forever or could I somehow restore them in the future by re-opening the Apps account? Will my YouTube videos disappear from the site? Are they lost forever? Or the reverse – do they stay on YouTube forever and become impossible to take down?

Comment: If you delete the account, the information will eventually will be deleted. The time frame could vary between services, I don't know the specific time frame for Youtube videos and Play Store purchases.