# Transfer Google reviews to another Gmail account

Tags: google-account

For years I have had my Gmail account however now it has been overrun by spam and such. I created a new Gmail account but the problem is that all of my Google reviews 100+ are on my old gmail account.

Is there a way to transfer all of my reviews to my new Gmail account? Also I have some games that I play on my mobile device that are on my old gmail account is there a way to transfer these as well?

Comment: Related: [Closing Google Apps account: Can I migrate YouTube account and Android Apps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91468/88163)

Comment: Are these place reviews (Google Maps / Local Guides)?

Answer (score 1):

If these are Google Maps / Local Guides reviews, then the [Local Guides Program Terms and Conditions](https://maps.google.com/localguides/rules) states:

> Contributions to Google Maps must originate from a single Google account to count towards benefits and cannot be transferred between owned accounts.

This question was also asked in [Local Guides Connect](https://www.localguidesconnect.com/t5/General-Discussion/Move-reviews-from-one-Google-account-to-another/m-p/93454#M128171) (27 Dec. 2016).