# Deactivate Google Workspaces but keep account as a normal free Google account

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I have a client who had a one-person business, and he used Google Workspaces, and his account was hisname@hisdomain.com. He used this account for work emails but also personal things like YouTube. Now he has closed the business. He doesn't want to continue paying for Google Workspaces. He has pointed his domain's MX records to a different email provider.

The issue is that he wants to keep using his Google Account for things like YouTube, without paying for a Google Workspaces subscription.

I can see that it's possible to have [a free Google Account with a non-Google email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en#existingemail), but I hope it's possible to convert his Google Workspaces account into this type of free account.

Can anyone share any advice about whether this is possible, and how to do it?

I think my question is very similar to these two, but hopefully there is new functionality available now, because they are old and they both say that what I want is impossible:

- [How to Migrate Google Apps account to regular Google Account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44567/how-to-migrate-google-apps-account-to-regular-google-account?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Closing Google Apps account: Can I migrate YouTube account and Android Apps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91468/closing-google-apps-account-can-i-migrate-youtube-account-and-android-apps)