# Is there a way to transform a (free) Google Apps User Account into a Google Account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account

The title basically says it:

I have a Google Apps User Account within a free Apps-organization. Is there are possibility for me or for the administrator of the organization to dissociate the account or to change its status into a normal personal Google Account.

I read [How do I migrate a Gmail account to a Google Apps Account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-do-i-migrate-a-gmail-account-to-a-google-apps-account/) and saw that for example Google+ stuff cannot be migrated.

I have seen people in my circles having several accounts at Google (apps and non-apps). Is this the way to do things?

Answer (score 1):

A paid or unpaid Google Apps account can not be transformed into a free Gmail account. With Google Apps accounts, you have the option to set your own domain name as your email address. You are not able to have a personal Gmail account with a custom domain name, it must be "@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1):

If you can't switch over the account, you can start a free trial of Spanning Backup for Google Apps (https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=68+17631887083757151838), export your data and then re-import it once you've created the new account.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? If so, you have to disclose this information in your answer. Please see the [help/behavior].