# Change Google Apps account

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I use Google Apps a long time.
Recently I created a domain and set up the Google Apps, but he is no longer free.
I found that in some ancient accounts, I have to add new e-mail accounts, including adding fields and have emails to these areas.

My question is on the migration of Google Apps paid to another account which is free.

Is there a way to transfer emails and files (drive) to the new account?

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-do-i-migrate-a-gmail-account-to-a-google-apps-account?rq=1.

Comment: I want to migrate the Google Apps for Works to Google Apps (free edition) ~all emails and all files to google drive.

Answer (score 1):

Email yes; files not directly.

You can retrieve all emails using POP (or IMAP) registering an external account from the new legacy account to be retrieved from POP.

Files could be shared on an entire folder from your old drive to the new one and then from the new account you would better make a new copy of the entire folder so it is owned by the new user (since ownership can't be passed to external users).