# How do I "enable" and existing e-mail address on my Google account?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator, migration

I have an existing e-mail address (hosted using Exchange) that I use for my Google account (for Calendar and Docs, etc.) and now want to enable e-mail on that account as well. I've found information on how to migrate account contents once I've enabled e-mail, but it's not clear from what I've found how to enable e-mail in the first place.

Starting from a state where I have an existing Google account for `me@abc.xyz` (for Calendar and Docs, etc.) with the e-mail address hosted on Exchange, how do I get to a state where `me@abc.xyz` is hosted fully on my Google account (Mail in addition to Calendar and Docs, etc.)?

---

([If it matters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143608/140429), the next thing I'll want to do is "upgrade" to G-Suite with `me@abc.xyz` as the Super Admin.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I migrate a Gmail account to a Google Apps Account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-do-i-migrate-a-gmail-account-to-a-google-apps-account)

Comment: @Rubén: No, precisely not. That's about an existing Google mail account which exactly what I don't have in this scenario!

Answer (score -1):

Your first step is to sign-up into G Suite

1. Go to https://gsuite.google.com
2. Click the Get started button
3. Fill up the form / follow the instructions